# Which services are considered Infrastructure Services?

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

[From:](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/)

> An Infrastructure Service would be something like our IEmailSender,
>   that communicates directly with external resources, such as the file
>   system, registry, SMTP, database, etc.  Something like NHibernate
>   would show up in the Infrastructure.

[From:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933351/if-you-are-forced-to-use-an-anemic-domain-model-where-do-you-put-your-businessInfrastructure%20Services)

> Used to abstract technical concerns (e.g. MSMQ, email provider, etc)

a)  are *persistence objects* ( ie Repositories / DAL ) also considered *Infrastructure services* ( according to the above quote they are )?

b) are all services that communicate with external resources and are not part of the primary problem domain ( ie removing them affects the application, but it doesn't affect the core domain problem ) considered *Infrastructure services*?

c) besides those services that communicating directly with the external resources, are there any other types of services which also fall under the umbrella of *Infrastructure services*?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

> Used to abstract technical concerns (e.g. MSMQ, email provider, etc)

as the main rule. **Infrastructure service is something that hides underlying technology details.** It's basically something that you'd change when you move from one technology to another (a particular mail client library; messaging queue implementation, data storage, logging routines, etc, etc up to entire .net framework and computer architecture).

So - repository/dal interfaces are part of domain as they construct objects from a persistent state. Their implementations (sometimes pluggable) are infrastructure part.

(And sorry but I assume b) and c) as more theoretical questions, which can be answered considering a particular application only).

Comment: At what layer do most Infrastructure services live? Namely, I've read that they are part of a BLL layer, but at least with DAL/Repository implementations, this isn't the case. Perhaps Infrastructure Service's interfaces do indeed always reside within BLL, but their implementations don't?

Comment: I'd say it's not a layer, but rather a vertical pillar, which provides infrastructure for all layers. Something similar to "cross-cutting" at [this webapp diagram](http://freekleemhuis.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/webapp.jpg). Just imagine "logging" which is used from everywhere.